# Is there a way to retain the state of a child stateful widget?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, stateful, flutter-pageview

Hy guys, I'm kinda new to this thing but pls is there any way one could retain the state of a stateful widget instead of rebuilding the widget each time it is called

--Let's say I have a PageView as my home page and its children are all stateful widgets...
and on page swipe I want it to build the child in the list once
instead of rebuilding on each page-change

--Here's my code,

!!!

```
return PageView(

onPageChanged: (cardIndex) {},

scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,

children: <Widget>[

ChatPage(),

UploadPage(),

NotifyPage(),

Settings()

]
);
```

...thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mixin class called `AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin` in your State class and override the `wantKeepAlive` method and return `true`.

Example:

```
class ChatPage extends StatefulWidget{
   @override
  _ChatPageState createState() => _ChatPageState();
}

class _ChatPageState extends State<ChatPage> with
   AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin<ChatPage> {

 @override
 bool get wantKeepAlive => true;   // <- override this method

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ....
  }
}
```

For more information, you can refer to this article which implements Persistent Tab bars  in Flutter https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-persistent-tab-bars-a26220d322bc